# Average over a relationship in django

Tags: python, django, orm, entity-relationship

I have two entities, namely Project and Issue defined as followed:

```
class Project(models.Model):

class Issue(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='issues')
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I'd like to have a progress method in the Project model that would return the average of the related Issue progress.

I tried the following but I'm getting the related issue list.

```
def progress(self):
    return self.issues.annotate(models.Avg('progress'))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is:

```
def progress(self):
    aggregate = self.issues.aggregate(models.Avg('progress'))
    return aggregate['progress_avg']
```

If you do intend to show the progress of each project in a project list view, then use something like:

```
for project in Project.objects.annotate(progress_avg=models.Avg('issues__progress')):
    print project.progress_avg
```

The latter example would be better for a list view, since it avoids an N+1 problem (1 aggregation query for each project in the list).

Comment: That's why a `progress__avg` appeared in each Issue! Thanks to you I now do get the difference. NB: there are two underscore at `progress__avg` (maybe escaping problem of the forum).